# Vue, how do I proxy everything excluding a specific path?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I would like the `webpack-dev-server` (underneath Vue CLI) to proxy everything that doesn't begin with `/app` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, how can I achieve this?

For example:

- http://localhost:8080/app served by `webpack-dev-server`
- http://localhost:8080/app/questions served by `webpack-dev-server`
- http://localhost:8080/ proxied to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
- http://localhost:8080/about-us proxied to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

I've tried this inside my `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devServer: {
            port: 8080,
            proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000!/app/**',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this using [vue-cli-plugin-proxy](https://github.com/deraw/vue-cli-plugin-proxy). After installing it, I added the following to my `vue.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/app',

    pluginOptions: {
        proxy: {
            context: '!/app/**',
            options: {
                target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining bypass function in your proxy settings like this.

```
devServer: {
    index: '', // specify to enable root proxying
    proxy: [{
        context: () => true,
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
        bypass: (req) => {
          if (req.url.startsWith('/app')) {
            return req.url // do not proxy
          }
          return false
        }
    }],
}
```

Comment: This works well, except that I can't get the root to proxy through. `http://localhost:8080/` does not proxy to `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: @Matt As per [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), dev server does not proxy root path by default. See the updated answer to get it working.

Comment: Thanks @Nafees - I'm still having issues with the root, I've posted an answer to outline them.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use Regex to match url excluding a prefix:

```
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
        "^(?!/app)": {
            target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to improve the formatting of your answer and tell us what this solves that was not solved by previous answers

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me when trying to proxy everything apart from the webpack hotreload socket. The "bypass" method did not work in this instance - perhaps it doesn't work for websockets.

Answer (score 1):

As per Nafees's answer, the following code enables me to access `/app/` and every other URL gets proxied. All except `/`, which doesn't get forwarded to the proxy.

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/app/',

    configureWebpack: {
        devServer: {
            index: '',
            proxy: {
                '/': {
                    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
                    bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
                        if (req.url.startsWith('/app/')) {
                            return req.url;
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```